# Is it possible to use Graphics2D instead of using OpenGL when making android games?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, graphics2d

I'm starting to learn how to develop android games. I was getting onto the graphical side of it (watching tutorials, reading code...) and I noticed that ALL of the sources I was looking at ONLY used OpenGL.

I tried to follow the tutorials as best I could (Copied the code 100% correctly) and it still doesn't work! And on top of that its REALLY CONFUSING!

I mean just look at it...

```
gl.glTranslatef(x, y, 0.0f);
gl.glScalef(width, height, 1.0f);
gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);
gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK);
gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indexBuffer);
gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
```

So is there anyway of using Graphics2D on android instead? I hope so.

Comment: I'm no Android expert, not by a long shot, but I fear that the answer to this question is likely "NO", that you will need to learn OpenGL graphics. But fear not, with continued effort, it *will* come to you.

Comment: More information to be found here:[android equivalent code for graphics2D](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15836712/android-equivalent-code-for-graphics2d), and in your question *may* be a duplicate of the link question, but I'm not going to dup-hammer your question given my severe ignorance of the android world.

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler solution would be to use: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html